# Run Shared Memory program on cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, shared-memory

I have tried to run the following code on cygwin in windows; there will be no compilation errors in it but when I tried to run it I have ***Bad system call (core dumped)*** error.

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/ipc.h> 
 #include <sys/shm.h> 
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <stdlib.h>
 void main ( ) 
 { int shm_id; key_t mem_key;
 int *shm_ptr; 
 mem_key = ftok(".", 'a'); 
 shm_id = shmget(mem_key, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
 if (shm_id < 0) 
 { printf("*** shmget error (server) ***\n");
 exit(1);
 }
 shm_ptr = (int *) shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0); 
 /* attach */ 
 if ((int) shm_ptr == -1) 
 {
 printf("*** shmat error (server) ***\n");
 exit(1);
 } 
}
```

Why I have this error? Can I solve it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure and start cygserver.